# NumberFormatter grouping not working as expected

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting

Working on currency formatting, I've found an issue when trying to format Chilean pesos.

Following this code:

```
let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
priceFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_CL")
priceFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
priceFormatter.currencyCode = "CLP"

priceFormatter.string(from: 9990) // A
priceFormatter.string(from: 99900) // B
```

Executing this I get **$9990** for **A** and **$99.990** for **B**.
What I want to achieve is **$9.990** for **A**

Looks like the formatter is not adding the thousand grouping separator on the first case, which I am not sure why. I have tried adding setting the `groupingSize` to 3 without success.

(This only happens with 4 digits)

Comment: You say "I want to achieve". But perhaps that is in fact the Chilean convention: the thousands separator is added only for values upwards of 10000. Maybe the number formatter knows better than we do.

Comment: Following this: https://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat
I see that CLP is marked as #.###

Comment: I'm with you, but that doesn't tell us what NumberFormatter thinks. :) My point is, it isn't possible to tell from here whether this is a bug or a difference of opinion. If you change the locale to `en_US` you get the separator in both cases. I tend to believe that the NumberFormatter knows more about the local conventions than I do. If you change your expectations you might be happier. :)

Comment: I tested this on a web-page with javascript examples you could change and got the exact same behaviour for CLP so I think we can assume the NumberFormatter is correct (or at least as good as its javascript counterpart :)).

Comment: If I try this it on JS I get $9.990:
`var number = 9990;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CLP' }).format(number));
`

Comment: It seems it is a problem related to iOS 13.

I'm having exactly the same problem using `es_ES`. It would be nice to check if it happens to any other locales, or just to the ones referring to spanish language.

I've developed a little bit more the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58613256/1387646 (not sure if I should do something rather than linking my question, since both are related).

Also I've reported the problem to Apple: FB7416623 https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7416623

Comment: Per https://spanishnumbers.guide/numbers-in-spanish.html#decimals, “Numbers with only four digits must not be separated.”

Comment: @Rob is right, it's a matter of language. The RAE and the fundéu (the institutions that dictate how to use properly the Spanish language) say that for 4 digits number you don't have to add the thousand grouping separator. However they say that the thousand grouping separator should be a white space and not the .

More info here:
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT
https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/miles-6498/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and found explanation here:
[iOS13: NumberFormatter missing groupingSeparator when try to format 4 digits numbers with es_ES locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613256/ios13-numberformatter-missing-groupingseparator-when-try-to-format-4-digits-num)

I ended up setting us_US locale:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "us_US")
formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSize = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve the same thing, what I ended up doing was this:

```
let price: Double = 1000
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator = "."
currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
let balanceText = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))!

return "$" + balanceText
```