# iOS13: NumberFormatter missing groupingSeparator when try to format 4 digits numbers with es_ES locale

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I've updated my project to iOS 13 and I've realised that the price formatter I was using for formatting the prices has stopped working correctly.

The `groupingSeparator`, the symbol that groups the thousands, is missing for 4 digits numbers: from 1000 to 9999 when using a the Spanish locale `es_ES`.

Below there is a simple snipped to verify it.
`NumberFormatter` seems to be working perfectly for `en_US` locale and for numbers higher than 9999 but whenever use `es_ES` locale and try to format a 4 digits number, the `groupingSeparator` (thousands separator) is missing, so instead of getting 1.000, I'm getting 1000.

```swift
let enFormatter = NumberFormatter()
enFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
enFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
enFormatter.string(from: 1000)
enFormatter.string(from: 9999)
enFormatter.string(from: 10000)
enFormatter.string(from: 100000)

let esFormatter = NumberFormatter()
esFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
esFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
esFormatter.string(from: 1000)
esFormatter.string(from: 9999)
esFormatter.string(from: 10000)
esFormatter.string(from: 100000)
```

Just paste it into a playground and check the outputs.

[image: Different outputs for en_US and es_ES NumberFormatter]

Am I missing something?

So far I've reported the problem to Apple: `FB7416623`
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7416623 (not sure if the link works)

I'll keep this updated, but I would appreciate if anybody has more information about it.

Comment: Is it normal in Spain to show the grouping separator with just 4 digits?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544119/numberformatter-grouping-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Yes, it is normal.
Thanks a lot for the related link. It seems that it is related to more locale, not only `es_ES`

Comment: But see Rob’s comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607986/memory-issue-of-not-releasing-memory-when-popping-to-view-controller#comment103536031_58607986 I am not convinced there’s a bug here. It seems to me that the earlier behavior was the bug.

Comment: Thanks @matt, you were right, i've just checked it with the Royal Academy of the use of Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this article from the RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=PxrAnmVfND6FK0uGdT) (Real Academia de la Lengua Española: Royal Academy of the Spanish Language), and [this other one from the Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/miles-6498/) (Fundación del Español Urgente: Urgent Spanish Foundation), right now the rule is not to use the grouping separator for 4 digits number, and use a white space as a grouping separator for the rest of the cases. For example:

```
1000  -> 1000
15000 -> 15 000
```

However ISO rules recommend to keep the grouping separator even for 4 digits numbers.

Comment: Thanks for point at this! I have finished by doing this ugly thing:

```
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        // Locale.current for spanish devices will be "es_ES" with point character as thousands separator
        formatter.groupingSeparator = Locale.current.groupingSeparator
        formatter.decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator
```

Answer (score -1):

> I don’t recommend using your method. What you should do is return a
> function for the text;
>
> function addComma(number)     local left, num, right =
> string.match(number, '^([^%d]*%d)(%d*)(.-)$')     return
> left..(num:reverse():gsub('(%d%d%d)','%1,'):reverse())..right end All
> you have to do is call the function, and the function returns the text
> with commas. I use this for any game I have that I need currency
> displayed. Hope this helped!
>
> Also please note, this doesn’t add M+ , K+ , this adds a comma like it
> does in the Leaderboard. If you wish to know how to add M and K’s to
> your text here is a video that can explain it well for you;
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mov5znC3yOA
>
> What you do with that is just change what he does for the leaderboard
> and do it in the text.

Use AddComma function to solve this. As Kensizo said, all you have to do is call the function

https://devforum.roblox.com/t/custom-coin-gui-bug/345991/2